# While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen`, the Haste package `react-native` was found

Tags: react-native, expo

running expo start raises the following error:

**While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen`, the Haste package `react-native` was found. However the module `Libraries/NewAppScreen` could 
not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `C:\...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen(.native||.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
  * `C:\...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\NewAppScreen\index(.native||.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)`
Failed building JavaScript bundle.**

[expo-cli error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kATO1.jpg)

Expo CLI 3.11.1 environment info:

```
System:
  OS: Windows 10
Binaries:
  Yarn: 1.13.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
  npm: 6.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I forgot to update the "sdkVersion" to "36.0.0" in app.json after I upgraded my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Expo CLI before run your project.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: this started after upgrading expo-cli to 3.11.1. I swtched to the previous version but, it is still happening!

Comment: try to remove the node module folder & re-install again.